# Connect to a mysql embedded database from Excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, embedding

Is there any way to access the tables in a mysql embedded database from MS Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OleDB provider for MySQL within Excel and connect to the database.

Comment: Hi, and where can I get a OleDB for MySQL?